# What is hidden on this image?

Tags: visual, steganography

Here's the image:

[image: The image]

What is hidden on it and how was it made?

Comment: Pixelation at its best.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got it!

First attempt:

> I separated the RGB channels, XOR'd them with each other, inverted them, and arbitrarily assigned the results `R=~(R^G); G=~(R^B); B=~(G^B)` based on what would make the hair and skin hue broadly correct.

Result image:

> [image]

The result isn't correct, but it made whatever component caused the moire patterns drop out.

EDIT: I got it!

> The image is XOR'd with the function `(x*y)%256`.

---

Final image:

> [image: Final image]

Clean function:

> [image: Clean XOR background]

Comment: I was thinking of giving a hint in form of classic `x^y` map eventually, but I thought it would be too much. Congratulations.

Answer (score 12):

This is how far I got; I created a python script to create a background image that I substracted from the given image (**Update**):

> [image]

This is the Python script I used:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
src = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
def tf(p,i,j):
  return tuple([256-(x-(256-i*j)/64*64)%256 for x in p])
odata = [tf(src.getpixel((j,i)),i,j) for i in range(0,256) for j in range(0,256)]
img = Image.new('RGB', (256,256))
img.putdata(odata)
img.save('2.png')
```

So it's basically the same as the accepted answer, but there is some small error in there somewhere..

And this is the correct python script using XOR instead of difference:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
src = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
def tf(p,i,j):
  return tuple([(x^i*j)%256 for x in p])
odata = [tf(src.getpixel((j,i)),i,j) for i in range(0,256) for j in range(0,256)]
img = Image.new('RGB', (256,256))
img.putdata(odata)
img.save('3.png')
```

Comment: Looks like Ayanami Rei from Neon Genesis Evangelion

Comment: That's exactly who it is.

Comment: You're very close, it's Rei indeed. The image can be recovered with zero artifacts, though, using a very simple transformation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the details of your solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is someone hidden in the image. I put the image [here](http://magiceye.ecksdee.co.uk/) and got this:

> [image: MAGIC_PICTURE]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's too vague. It wouldn't be interesting if you could see it through Magic Eye :P

Comment: I can do magic eye puzzles, if I tried it with this image my eyes would fall out...